# SQL column with multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i want to know how can we store multiple values in a sql column, or which is the best way to store the values in a sql column.

Consider in a movie table, a movie will be having multiple Genre
eg,
Genre: "Action, Adventure, Fantasy"
Genre: "Adventure, Drama, Fantasy, Thriller"

which is the best way to store the Genre values in database.

Comment: The best way by far, is **NOT** to store multiple values in a column. It violates normal form.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a classic *n to m relation*. It works like this

```
movies table
------------
id
name
...


genres table
------------
id
name


movie_genres table
------------------
movie_id
genre_id
```

The `movie_genres` table then contains one record for each genre of a movie. Example:

```
movie_genres
------------
movie_id  |  genre_id
1         |  1
1         |  2
1         |  13
```

To get the genres of a movie do:

```
select g.name as genre_name
from genres g
join movie_genres mg on mg.genre_id = g.id
join movies m on m.id = mg.movie_id
where m.name = 'star wars'
```

Comment: then the genre table will be having a ton of rows, is it a good option? please help

Comment: This is the way to do it. The best option and the only normalized one. And even billions of records are no problem for a well indexed table.

Comment: @SijoJose The genre table won't have a ton of rows, but the movie_genres table will.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, using a [n:m relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)), as juergen_d suggested, is the best option.

But in mysql there is another option it might work in your case: using SET data type. Details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html). Defintely not as powerful nor robust as using n:m relationship. Not normalization friendly.